# Strategy definition in an extensive form game

Tags: mathematical-economics, game-theory, information

How a (pure ) strategy is defined in an extension form game with information sets? I would like to have both an intuitive and a formal definition.

Thank you in advance!

Comment: Does either of these answer your question: https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/16576, https://economics.stackexchange.com/q/15747

Comment: Does this answer your question? [When action and strategy differ in game theory](https://economics.stackexchange.com/questions/15747/when-action-and-strategy-differ-in-game-theory)